# Is it possible to drag UI Elements in a UWP app run on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

In my case, I created a local UWP app where the dragging worked great, but at the time I moved it to the Raspberry Pi 3 with Windows IoT Core (latest insider build), the drag event will fire, but no dragging occurs.

Is there any way to make this work within IoT Core/ARM? Or is there any trick for this?

Comment: Is the question that you're not seeing a drag animation?

Comment: The drag animation is also not there, but I'm actually asking why the dragging works on my laptop/x64 or x86 and doesn't work on the Pi with Windows IoT core and ARM cpu. Without this, I can't get the drop event to work.

Comment: What UI element do you use?

Comment: I use the TextBlock element.